# PHP error on signup page: Notice: Undefined index: signup in C:\xampp\htdocs\Marcus\signup.php on line 27

Tags: php

Hello I have setup my Signup page but I am getting this error `Notice: Undefined index: signup in C:\xampp\htdocs\Marcus\signup.php on line 27` The error is coming from my HTML as it uses $_GET to see the URL and see check to see if their are errors with the input of the form and to display error messages,the error messages and the success message do work its just when you click on the signup button and it goes into a different HTML the error shows up, but as soon as one of the errors are true it goes away. any help at all would be great!

HTML for my signup page

```
require "header.php";

 ?>

<main>
<h1 class="signup_text2">Signup</h1>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <?php


        if (isset($_GET['error'])) {
          if ($_GET['error'] == "emptyfields") {
            echo '<p class="error1"> Fill in all feilds!!</p>';
          }elseif ($_GET['error'] == "invaildmailuid") {
            echo '<p class="error2"> Invalid Username And Email! </p>';
          }elseif ($_GET['error'] == "invaliduid") {
            echo '<p class="error3"> Invalid Username </p>';
          }elseif ($_GET['error'] == "invalidmail") {
            echo '<p class="error4"> Invalid E-mail! </p>';
          }elseif ($_GET['error'] == "passswordcheck") {
            echo '<p class="error5"> Your Passwords do not match! </p>';
          }elseif ($_GET['error'] == "usertaken") {
            echo '<p class="error6"> Username is already taken! </p>';
          }
        }elseif ($_GET['signup'] == "success") {
          echo '<p class="success1"> Signup Successful!</p>';
        }
    ?>
<form action="includes/signup.inc.php" method="post">
    <input class="signup-Username" type="text" name="uid" placeholder="Username">
    <input class="signup-Email" type="text" name="mail" placeholder="E-mail">
    <input class="signup-Password" type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password">
    <input class="signup-Password2" type="password" name="pwd-repeat" placeholder="Repeat Password">
    <button class="signup_btn" type="sumbit" name="signup-submit">Signup</button>
</form>


</main>
```

PHP signup code

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['signup-submit'])) {

    require 'dbh.inc.php';


    $username = $_POST['uid'];
    $email = $_POST['mail'];
    $password = $_POST['pwd'];
    $passwordRepeat = $_POST['pwd-repeat'];

    if (empty($username) || empty($email) || empty($password) || empty($passwordRepeat)) {
        header("Location: ../signup.php?error=emptyfields&uid=".$username."&mail=".$email);
        exit();
    }elseif (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) && !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $username)) {
        header("Location: ../signup.php?error=invaildmailuid");
        exit();
    }elseif (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        header("Location: ../signup.php?error=invaildmail&uid=".$username);
        exit();
    }elseif (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $username)) {
        header("Location: ../signup.php?error=invailduid&mail=".$email);
        exit();
    }elseif ($password !== $passwordRepeat) {
        header("Location: ../signup.php?error=passwordcheck&uid=".$username."&mail=".$email);
        exit(); 
    }else{
        $sql = "SELECT uidUsers FROM users WHERE uidUsers=?";
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
            header("Location: ../signup.php?error=sqlerror1");
            exit();
        } else {
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $username);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
            $resultCheck = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);
            if ($resultCheck > 0) {
                header("Location: ../signup.php?error=usertaken&mail=".$email);
                exit();
            } else {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO users (uidUsers, emailUsers, pwdUsers) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
                $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
                if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
                    header("Location: ../signup.php?error=sqlerror");
                    exit();
                    } else {
                        $hashedPwd = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);


                        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $username, $email, $hashedPwd);
                        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                        header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=success");
                        exit();
                    }




            }


        }



    }
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    mysqli_close($conn);


}else {
    header("Location: ../signup.php");
    exit();

}
```

Comment: You just need to use `isset($_GET['signup'])` before you try and access the value i.e. `elseif (isset($_GET['signup']) && $_GET['signup'] == "success") {`

Comment: @Nick thank you Nick, I changed that and now the problem is fixed